# Travelling to Greece while having got passport stamped at Ercan Airport in Northern Cyprus

Tags: greece, northern-cyprus

i am an EU citizen and was wondering if i was going to travel to Greece would the authorities in Greece have any problems with Ercan Airport stamp in my passport? Or perhaps i should just show them my ID card instead?

Comment: Once ypu have proven your EU Citizenship, you must be let in. In theory there is no immigration control (i.e. checking of passport stamps) for EU Citizens. In this case, however, it might be prudent to prove you citizenship with your ID card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, that is an answer, please post it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have proven your EU Citizenship, you must be let in.

In theory there is no immigration control (i.e. checking of passport stamps) for EU Citizens.

In this case, however, it might be prudent to prove you citizenship with your ID card.